# HTML page is not shown

Tags: django

when I click on about, it does not go in about.html page and not show any error.
here is the link for calling

```
<li><a href="{%url 'about'%}">About</a> </li>
```

url

```
url(r'^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name  = 'about')
```

and, view,py

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
template_name  = 'about.html'
```

Comment: Did you try `{% url 'about' %}`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but not working.

Comment: Look at the source HTML in your browser. What's the link?

Comment: And if the link is correct, look at the Network tab of your browser debug tools. What's the request (if any) that's being sent? And what's the response?

Comment: @dirkgroten, I checked it, the link is correct. when I click on, it shows the home page.

Comment: So in the network tab you see a request for the page and a response which is the home page?

Comment: @AliRazaJaveed If the link is correct, but it's showing you the home page instead of  your about page, there should be shomething wrong with your `AboutView` logic; Are you rendering the correct template there?